# How can I mount a UFS drive in linux?

Tags: linux, truenas, openfiler

I am considering switching from FreeNAS to OpenFiler. One issue I see with this is that all the hard drives in my NAS are formatted to UFS. I tried but was unable to mount them in Fedora. Is there any way I can extract my data from the UFS hard drive without a FreeBSD OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux should be able to mount UFS easily as read-only. Try modprobe ufs2 if it has trouble mounting it.

What distro are you using?

Comment: I am using Fedora 10

Comment: Here's a message from June 2008 the says UFS had r/o kernel support: 
http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2008-06/msg02466.html

I'd say you are fine

Comment: Hmm, I will give it another go, I don't recall the exact error I was getting.

Comment: Cool. I'm interested in hearing about it. Drop me a line or just reply here once you get a chance

Answer (score 7):

UFS2 read only support is included into linux kernel since version 2.6.5.
For example:

```
mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 -o ro  /dev/hda3 /mnt/bsd/
```

You still need an extra HDD to copy data from UFS drive.